# R: Creating one table featuring two different normal distributions

Tags: r

I would like to create a table comprised of 100 players. I would then like to generate two normal distributions to calculate their score before (with a mean of 6) and after changing hardware (with a mean of 4)

```
data <- tibble(

playerID = rep(1:100, each = 2), 
hardwareImproved =  rep(c(FALSE,TRUE), 100),
playerScore =  rep(c(rnorm(100,6,1),
               rnorm(100,4,1)),
               1),
```

)

I believe what is happening is that I am getting the first half of the total players with the score before and the second half after the hardware change. What I want is to alternate between normal distributions as so:

```
Player ID, hardware improved, Score
1, false, (normal distribution 1)
1, true, (normal distribution 2)
2, false, (normal distribution 1)
2, true, (normal distribution 2)
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `hardwareImproved` is alternative true/false/true/false but your data is first-half mu=6, second-half mu=4, it indicates that you are alternating incorrectly.

Noting the difference between `rep(., each=)` and `rep(., times=)`:

```r
rep(c(T,F), times=3)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
rep(c(T,F), each=3)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

We can do:

```r
set.seed(42)
data <- tibble(
  playerID = rep(1:100, times = 2),
  hardwareImproved = rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each = 100),
  playerScore = c(rnorm(100, 6, 1), rnorm(100, 4, 1))
)
data
# # A tibble: 200 x 3
#    playerID hardwareImproved playerScore
#       <int> <lgl>                  <dbl>
#  1        1 FALSE                   7.37
#  2        2 FALSE                   5.44
#  3        3 FALSE                   6.36
#  4        4 FALSE                   6.63
#  5        5 FALSE                   6.40
#  6        6 FALSE                   5.89
#  7        7 FALSE                   7.51
#  8        8 FALSE                   5.91
#  9        9 FALSE                   8.02
# 10       10 FALSE                   5.94
# # ... with 190 more rows
data %>%
  group_by(hardwareImproved) %>%
  summarize(mu = mean(playerScore))
# `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   hardwareImproved    mu
#   <lgl>            <dbl>
# 1 FALSE             6.03
# 2 TRUE              3.91
```

If you really want them ordered first by player then by "improved", then

```r
data <- data %>%
  arrange(playerID, hardwareImproved)
data
# # A tibble: 200 x 3
#    playerID hardwareImproved playerScore
#       <int> <lgl>                  <dbl>
#  1        1 FALSE                   7.37
#  2        1 TRUE                    5.20
#  3        2 FALSE                   5.44
#  4        2 TRUE                    5.04
#  5        3 FALSE                   6.36
#  6        3 TRUE                    3.00
#  7        4 FALSE                   6.63
#  8        4 TRUE                    5.85
#  9        5 FALSE                   6.40
# 10        5 TRUE                    3.33
# # ... with 190 more rows
```

though this does not change the actual data, just its order/representation.